# Error in section title formatting after including color package

Tags: formatting, color, miktex

I am using `TeXnicCenter` to write my latex document. I am formatting my section heading using following command:

```
 \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

This command is working fine, but when I include package "color" it starts giving me error. Please let me know, how to correct it.

Following is the error:

1. `Missing number treated as zero`
2. `Color stack action is missing`

It also display **"POP"** in the section heading in pdf file.

Following is the sample code:

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{report}
  \usepackage{url}
  \usepackage{color}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
     \usepackage{cite}
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
     \usepackage{titlesec}

      \titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}

      \begin{document}

     \chapter{NewChap}
     \section{Hello}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{%
    \normalfont%
    \fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont%
    \bfseries%
%   \MakeUppercase
}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}

\chapter{NewChap}
\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sangeeta You're welcome! As soon as a question has a MWE answering becomes much easier :)